# Windows Forms Chart: How to disable X primary axis and keep X seconday axis tick labels?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, charts, axis-labels

I am trying to have a Chart that only displays the secondary X axis (top axis) but whenever I disable the primary X axis (bottom), the secondary X axis tick labels disapears...

When I enable secondary axis:

```
chartArea1.AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

[image: X2 axis enabled]

When I disable seconday axis:

```
chartArea1.AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```

[image: X1 axis disabled]

I have been trying many things but I could not find a solution that did not look like a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of turning it off you can style it to disappear:

```
Axis axis = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0];   // your indices
LabelStyle als = new LabelStyle();
als.ForeColor = chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor; 
axis.LabelStyle = als;
axis.MajorTickMark.TickMarkStyle = TickMarkStyle.None;
```

Comment: This solution is good enough for me. But instead I set the BackColor to Transparent so I am sure the text will never appear. Thanks!